# Destroy and rebuild directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Consider the following code block.

Controller

```
function($scope){
   var currentIndex = 1,
   shapes = [{type:'square',/*...*/},{type:'triangle',/*...*/},{type:'triangle',/*...*/},],

   $scope.goToNextShape = function(){
        currentIndex++
        $scope.currentShape = shapes[currentIndex]
   }

}
```

HTML

```
<square data="currentShape" ng-if="currentShape.type = 'square'" />
<circle data="currentShape"  ng-if="currentShape.type = 'circle'" />
<triangle data="currentShape" ng-if="currentShape.type = 'triangle'" />
<rectangle data="currentShape"  ng-if="currentShape.type = 'rectangle'" />
<trapezoid data="currentShape" ng-if="currentShape.type = 'trapezoid'" />
<button ng-click="goToNextShape()></button>
```

I show one shape at a time, and each shape is rendered via its own directive. The directive utilizes other components that have animations and other functionality. Currently if I have a circle after a square object, all is great because the directive is destroyed due to the ng-if and a circle is built. However if I have two squares back to back, then the directive does not get rebuilt because the ng-if stays the same. How can I make angular destroy and rebuild the directive when I `goToNextShape()`

Comment: That's not valid HTML. And it's not nearly enough code to illustrate your problem.

Comment: the html is sufficient for this purpose of this question. This code is a bit confusing, I'll will rewrite.

Comment: Now I understand the problem. What I don't understand, though, is why you want the directive to be rebuilt. In other words: What would be different?

Comment: There are a ton of little things and also sub-directives and templates that I'm having to go through and hack solutions to fix errors that could easily be solved if, between iterations, I could just kill the directive. A lot of these issues were not seen in testing because of course you test each of the 5 shapes and thus the directive is automatically destroyed. I think my solution would be to simply have the iterator make data.shape = null and run a digest before moving on. If that works I'll post as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did actually made for a good ux experience as well. I have a shape loading screen in-between shapes. When that screen is on, I destroy my current shape by putting into a parent element with an ng-if.

HTML

```
<!-- when shapeIsLoaded = false all directives will be destroyed --->
<!-- just need to make sure a digest cycle is run between shapeIsLoaded switching between true / false --->    
<div ng-if="shapeIsLoaded">
  <square data="currentShape" ng-if="currentShape.type = 'square'" />
  <circle data="currentShape"  ng-if="currentShape.type = 'circle'" />
  <triangle data="currentShape" ng-if="currentShape.type = 'triangle'" />
  <rectangle data="currentShape"  ng-if="currentShape.type = 'rectangle'" />
  <trapezoid data="currentShape" ng-if="currentShape.type = 'trapezoid'" />
  <button ng-click="goToNextShape()></button>
</div>
```